# Modular arithmetic and powers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Suppose: $$a=(5^4 \pmod 7)^3 \pmod {13}$$

How would you go about solving this?
The only thing I came up with is an ugly polynomial: $a=13k+7l^3+5^{12}$ but this doesn't tell me much. Any starting point would be great.

Comment: hint: $(5^4 \pmod 7)=2$

Comment: gosh you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$5^2\mod 7 = -3$$
   $$5^4 \mod 7 = 2$$.
 $$2^3=8$$.